# Can $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{-n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$ be considered as a valid power series?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, singularity

I'm asked to look at $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{-n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$$ and decide whether it's a fine power series, and if so: then around which point it's developed. Since I know a power series is of the form: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n(x-x_0)^n}$$ I can say right away that: $$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ All of the examples I've seen until today never included $x$ (or $x^n$ for that matter) at the denominator. 
Suppose such form exists, I can assume the series is developed around $x_0=0$.
And here's my dillemma:

Suppose such series does exist, hence the domain of $x$ so that this power series converges is $|x|>1$, since our $x$ is in the denominator. Can that series still be considered valid if it's developed around $x=0$ but $x$ has to be greater than 1?

From all the $x$'s in $\mathbb{R}$, $x=0$ is the only value that is a singular point.
Since this is a singular point and the function to which this series converges to is not analytic at $x=0$ can this series can still be called a valid power series? (would it be a valid one if it were: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x-3)^{-n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$ for example?).

I would appriciate it if someone could clarify it for me.

Comment: Let $y=1/x$, then it's a power series in $y$.

Comment: But x has to be greater than 1. My question is whether developing the series around $x=0$ is a contradiction (or not?) to the domain of convergence.

Comment: Around $x=0$, you can't, as this does not converge.

Comment: By your definition, it is not a power series.

Comment: =$L{{i}_{\frac{1}{2}}}\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$

Comment: but still, around x=0, so it's should raise a red flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) (which is a generalization of power series) with inner radius of convergence $1$ and outer radius of convergence $\infty$; in other words, it converges for $|x|>1$ (and also, as it happens, at $x=-1$).

Comment: I assumed this is the kind of series presented to me, but since x is not in my domain, can this power series be considered valid around it?